# Calling Javascript from service android

Tags: android, android-service

I want to connect my android app to WAMP server. I'm using javascript to do it. I have a activity where I load an HTML file. Internally, the HTML file  will load that javascript.

I want the server continues to run even when the phone is locked.

Now, the server connection drops when the phone is locked.

**Follows the code of my activity:**

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptInterface(this), "JSInterface");
mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

mWebView.setWebViewClient(
    new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.d(TAG,"Page loading finished");
            
            String ip = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:configureServerIp('"+ ip + "')");
        }
    }
);
```

**Follows my JS file:**

```
function configureServerIp(ip) {
    console.log("ip=>"+ip)
    if(ip != null) {
        connection = new autobahn.Connection({url: 'ws://'+ip+':8080/ws', realm: 'realm1'});

        connection.onopen = function (session) {
            openSession = session;
            console.log("SESSION: " + session);
            session.subscribe('bms.device.msg',onevent)
            session.subscribe('bms.device.request.location',onLocationRequest)
            session.subscribe('bms.device.request.config',onConfigRequest)
            window.JSInterface.isConnected(true);
        };

        connection.onClose = function(reason, details) {
            openSession = null;
            window.JSInterface.isConnected(false);
        }

        connection.open();

    }
}
```

Is there any way, we can call javascript function from a service? If it is possible, will allow make the server running even when the app is not in foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created `WebView` object inside my *service* and I got my js function called successfully.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    webView = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(
        new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                
                for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:sample()");
                }

            }
        }
    );
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: if it exists, i want to use the same WebView object that the UI owns (it has state I need)... is that possible?